# Using the &= on boolean with a start value of false?

Tags: javascript, c#, boolean

Given the following code:

```
var bolValue = true; //or bool bolValue if in C#
bolValue &= someBooleanExpression;
bolValue &= anotherBooleanExpression;
....
```

The end result of bolValue is true or false and each expression evaluated only if the value of bolValue is true when that line of code is executed. For this to work, the starting value of bolValue *must* be true.

How would that be rewritten to allow for a starting value of false and allowing it to go through each expression only if the value of bolValue is false before each &= evaluation?

Comment: What is your goal? `False` and ANYTHING is always `False`. In other words, if you start with `False`, then there is no need to evaluate any other `&=` statements.

Comment: It is futile to initialize `bolValue` to `false` and then using `&=` on it. No matter what any of those expressions evaluate to (either `true` or `false`), in the end `bolValue` will always be `false`.

Comment: Please try to restate your question, as it doesn't make any sense.

Comment: |= ? Why hadn't I thought of this??? argh. Thanks. It doesn't asnwer as asked but it provides me with what I"m looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Opertor &= should be used for bit masks, not boolean variables.
something like

```
char flags = 0x4fee;
char A_mask = 0x0001;
flags &= A_mask; // <=> flags = flags & mask;(bitwise AND here)
```

So do not use it for booleans as it's not for them.

For booleans you can use that one:

`var result = condition1 && condition2 && condition3 && condition4 ... ;`

Comment: The logical operators work with Booleans. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691309(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @RufusL: `&=` is not a logical operator in Javascript.

Comment: @RufusL Why do you post a reference for C#, when he asked specifically for javascript.

Comment: Well, it is the combination of a logical operation and an assignement

Comment: Why is it bad? It specifically states in the documentation that for Booleans it is a logical AND. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02.aspx

Comment: @Heron Well, he did not specifically ask for JavaScript, though, did he?

Comment: and even for c# it's bad to use &= operator for boolean logic, as it makes code less clear

Answer (score -1):

What I think you should do is:

```
var boolValue = Expr1 || Expr2 || ...
```

Because of [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), if it finds an expression that evaluates to true, it will stop evaluating the other expressions and assign true to your variable, else it will evaluate the next expression and so on.

Comment: That doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Guffa I think it does. "How would that be rewritten to allow for a starting value of false and allowing it to go through each expression only if the value of bolValue is false". This does exactly what he asked for.

Comment: No, it does't because that is not possible.

Comment: @Guffa Please read about short-circuit evaluation. This just skips the value initialization and just does the check.

Comment: Please don't take that tone.

Comment: @Guffa I am sorry if my tone bothered you, but could you please bring an argument to sustain your statement?

Comment: The OP specifically asked for a starting value of `false`. The code that you suggested doesn't use that starting value at all. Code that does use the starting value in the way requested doesn't give a correct result.

Comment: That's true, but the OP's request makes little sense, and this code is almost certainly what should be done (this, or something like `Array.prototype.find()`)

Comment: @Pointy: That's beside the point. Heron himself advocated that the question should be answered, and this doesn't answer the question.